# Unable to refresh all instances of spring cloud config client with spring cloud bus

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-bus

**Cloud Config Server Dependencies -**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-monitor:2.1.0.RELEASE'
```

**Cloud Config Client Dependencies -**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka:2.1.4.RELEASE'
```

**Properties config in Server side :**

```
spring.jmx.default-domain=cloudConfigServer
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=******************************* 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=***************** 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=********************* 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true
spring.cloud.bus.enabled = true 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers= kafka-broker:9092 
spring.cloud.bus.id= ${spring.application.name}:${spring.profiles.active}:${random.uuid}
management.security.enabled=false 
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* 
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true 
management.info.git.mode=full
```

**Properties in Client Side:**

```
spring.resources.chain.enabled=true
spring.cloud.bus.enabled = true 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers= kafka-broker:9092 spring.cloud.bus.id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.profiles.active}:${random.uuid}
management.security.enabled=false 
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* 
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true 
management.info.git.mode=full
health.config.enabled=false
hello.title=Test 16
```

This Config Client and Config Server both are already developed and I have added functionality of Spring Cloud Bus in it by adding specified dependency and configuration and kafka is used as messaging system.

Also I have added web hook in git repository setting.

I have verified in config server logs that if any refresh event occurs it showing in logs .

But Clients are not getting refreshed .

To refresh clients, I have triggered /actuator/bus-refresh on client side, and its refreshing only one instance.

I tried hitting /actuator/bus-refresh in server side but no luck.

What's wrong I am doing ?